# React: call setState from another component

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6

This is the parent component:

```
class Parent extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      news: ""
    }
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    this.updateNews();
  }

  updateNews = () => {
      ...
  }

  render() {
      <CustomButton type="primary"  />
  }
```

This is the `CustomButton`:

```
const CustomButton = (props) => {
  const {
    type
  } = props;


  const updateItem = () => {
     ... // The firing of the setState should be here
  }

  return (
   <Button
    type={type}
    onClick={() => {
        updateItem();
      }}
    >{value}
   </Button>
  );
```

How can I fire from inside `const updateItem = () => {` in `CustomButton`, so that `Parent` runs `updateNews` or `componentDidMount`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the componentDidUpdate in Parent component like this.

```
class Parent extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
   super(props);
   this.state = {
    news: "",
    fetchToggle:true
   }
  }
  componentDidMount() {
   this.updateNews();
  }

  componentDidUpdate(prevprops,prevstate){
    if(prevstate.fetchToggle!==this.state.fetchToggle){
       this.updateNews();
    }
  }
  updateNews = () => {
   ...
  }
  fetchToggle=()=>{
     this.setState({
      fetchToggle:!this.state.fetchToggle;
     })
   }

  render() {
    <CustomButton type="primary" fetchToggle={this.fetchToggle} />
  }
```

In the child component clicking on button call this toggle function.

```
const CustomButton = (props) => {
  const {
   type
  } = props;

  const updateItem = () => {
   ... // The firing of the setState should be here
  } 

  return (
   <Button
     type={type}
     onClick={() => {
       props.fetchToggle()
     }}
   >{value}
   </Button>
  );
```

Remember that a toggling value in state is a cleaner and elegant way to update or fetch latest data on every click.

Comment: How does it know from `CustomButton` that the `props.fetchToggle()` call another components function?

Comment: We pass the function as a callback to its children in general practice.The use of componentDidUpdate is this whenever the state is updated this function is fired.To call this function we have to update some value of state.So its best just use some value which has just two values like a bool.whenver you click button in custombutton this function is fired and the state is updated.This rerenders the page.If you don't use componentDidUpdate this is not possible as componentdidmount is run once only.

Answer (score 0):

You should pass a callback function to the CustomButton, something like that:

```
class Parent extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      news: ""
    }
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    this.updateNews();
  }

  updateNews = () => {
      ...
  }

  render() {
      <CustomButton type="primary"  stateUpdatingCallback={(val) => {this.setState({myVal: val})}}/>
  }


const CustomButton = (props) => {
  const {
    type
  } = props;


  const updateItem = () => {
     ... // The firing of the setState should be here
  }

  return (
   <Button
    type={type}
    onClick={() => {
        this.props.stateUpdatingCallback("somevalue")
      }}
    >{value}
   </Button>
);
```