# How do I call setState from another Component in ReactJs

Tags: reactjs, components, setstate

I have two react components and I'd like to call setState to set a state in the one Component but called in the other one.
How do I do that?

Comment: Have a function that sets the state on the parent component and pass that function to the child component.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52983102/react-call-setstate-from-another-component

Answer (score 61, accepted):

If you work with functional components you can use hooks like `useState`. Don't forget to "save" (memoize) the reference of your handler with `useCallback`, it helps React avoid useless rerenders.

***Functional component solution***

```
// myContainer.js
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import MyChild from 'some/path/myChild'

function MyContainer() {
  const [name, setName] = useState('foo')

  return (
    <MyChild name={name} onNameChange={setName} />
  )
}

export default MyContainer

// myChild.js
import React, { useCallback } from 'react'

function MyChild({ name, onNameChange }) {

  const handleInputChange = useCallback(event => {
    onNameChange(event.target.value)
  }, [onNameChange])

  return (
    <div>
      <input type="text" onChange={handleInputChange} value={name} />
      <div>The name is: {name}</div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default MyChild
```

In a class you can use handler (method) that contains some logic or function call(s). It help to keep your code maintainable.

***Class component solution***

```
// myContainer.js
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import MyChild from 'some/path/myChild'

class MyContainer extends Component {
  state = {
    name: 'foo'
  }

  handleNameChange = name => {
    this.setState({ name })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <MyChild name={this.state.name} onNameChange={this.handleNameChange} />
    )
  }

}

export default MyContainer

// myChild.js
import React, { Component } from 'react'

class MyChild extends Component {

  handleInputChange = event => {
    this.props.onNameChange(event.target.value)
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <input type="text" onChange={this.handleInputChange} value={this.props.name} />
        <div>The name is: {this.props.name}</div>
      </div>
    )
  }

}

export default MyChild
```

Comment: Hi, my situation is the inverse. Trying to change state in child functional component from a button click on the parent functional component. Also, there are multiple child components with a button each in a loop. How would I make sure only one of them updates? Thanks in advance!

Comment: @SanjivPradhanang Perhaps you could open a question thread, expose your issue with code example. That would be easier to propose solutions.

Answer (score 17):

You can't directly call `setState` on a parent component from a child component because the updating of a component state is restricted to the current component.

To handle this, simply pass a function from the parent to the child that contains `setState`. So when you want to update the parent's state, just call that passed function.

A minimal example:

```
// Parent.jsx

import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Child from './Child';

class Parent extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.setChanged = this.setChanged.bind(this);
    this.state = {
      changed: false
    }
  }

  // Function to set the parent's state
  setChanged() {
    this.setState({ changed: true });
  }

  render() {
    return <Child setChanged={this.setChanged} />
  }
}

// Child.js

import React from 'react';

function Child(props) {
  return (
    // When clicked, parent's setChanged function is called
    <div onClick={() => props.setChanged()} />
  )
}
```

Comment: thanks for your response although I went with Kornflexxs

Comment: TypeError: props.setChanged is not a function