# Set state from App.js component in login.js Component in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Well, I am trying to set the state of my App.js Component in the login.js component to true. The code  I  have in my App.js is this:

```
state = {
  isAuth: false
};
```

And this is how I try to set the isAuth to false in my login.js Component:

```
    statusCode:{
            200:  function(){
                this.App.state.isAuth = true;
                console.log('it's working!')
            }
        }
```

This is how I import the App Component:
`import App from './App';`

If the  user successfully login the status code should be 200 and after receiving this status code the  `isAuth` of the App.js component should be set to true. Don't know why this is not working. I'm getting the error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'state' of undefined.`

Comment: Do you mean to change value of ```isAuth``` to ```false```?

Comment: You probably didn't initialize `this.App`. You can use `React.createRef()` to create ref. But I think this design is problematic. Why don't you get state change via callback of login.js and set the state in App.js.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to `setState` directly from another component. So, one solution is to pass a function that handles the `setState` to the other component. For example, in your case:

App.js

```js
import Login from "path/to/Login"

class App extends Component {
  state = {
    isAuth: false
  }

  handleIsAuthChange = (isAuth) => {
    this.setState({ isAuth })
  }

  render () {
    return <Login handleIsAuthChange={this.handleIsAuthChange} />
  }
}
```

Then you can access the function by `props`

Login.js

```js
class Login extends Component {
  setIsAuth = (isAuth) => {
    this.props.handleIsAuthChange(isAuth)
  }
  
  // Your Code...
}
```

Another possible solution is to use the `Context API`, but this is certainly the easiest way to do it.

If you're still a little lost on this, I recommend you to take a look at this answer as well https://stackoverflow.com/a/55028734/11194008

Comment: Well, I have watched the link you posted but I'm still lost. May you please show me in my code what I have to do to set isAuth=true in the login.js component

Comment: Can you add the code snippet from `App.js` and `Login.js` please?

Comment: @masterYoda: You need to study react a bit more. Your mental model of how this works is making you confused. In your original code snippet you want to make this work as `this.App.state.isAuth=true`. Which not how this works.  You have to lift the state up and then perform your login activity there and pass is Auth as a prop to your App component.